# Firefox WebExtensions tabs.onUpdated incorrect argument

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm creating a simple webExtension for firefox and I want to use [tabs.onUpdated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/onUpdated) with a filter. I copied an example from mozilla site:

```
const pattern1 = "https://developer.mozilla.org/*";
const pattern2 = "https://twitter.com/mozdevnet";

const filter = {
  urls: [pattern1, pattern2]
}
function handleUpdated(tabId, changeInfo, tabInfo) {
  console.log(`Updated tab: ${tabId}`);
  console.log("Changed attributes: ", changeInfo);
  console.log("New tab Info: ", tabInfo);
}
browser.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(handleUpdated, filter);
```

When I reload my extension I get this error in console:

```
Error: Incorrect argument types for tabs.onUpdated.  background-script.js:14:1
  makeError resource://gre/modules/Schemas.jsm:446:14
  throwError resource://gre/modules/Schemas.jsm:2138:11
  checkParameters resource://gre/modules/Schemas.jsm:2195:7
  addStub resource://gre/modules/Schemas.jsm:2381:21
  <anonymous> moz-extension://78d98d27-294e-4774-9461-dfb3dda97871/background-script.js:14:1
```

I don't know if there was some changes in this api which wasn't documented yet or there is some other problem, maybe with permissions.

These are my permissions from `manifest.json`:

```
"permissions": ["activeTab", "notifications", "tabs"]
```

Comment: Do you have Firefox 61 or higher? extraParameters is supported from Firefox 61 onwards: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/onUpdated

Comment: That could be it. I have 60.0.2.

Comment: @Smile4ever It works, thank you a lot. Please make an answer from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

extraParameters is supported from Firefox 61 onwards: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/onUpdated

If you want to support an older version, you should use an "if" statement in your onUpdated listener.